# Ordering oddity with sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the SQL:

```
select
sub.id,
corr
from 
    (
        select
            m.id,
            m.sent_time,
            (case when m.to_user = '58' then m.from_user else m.to_user end) as corr
        from
            messages m
        where
            (
                from_user = '58' OR
                to_user = '58'
            )
        order by
            m.sent_time desc
    ) as sub
group by
    sub.corr
order by
    sent_time DESC
```

In a site's source code I have inherited.
The SQL retrieves the message ID and the user ID of the other party communicated with where messages have been sent to or from the logged in user (in this case user ID 58.

The query at the moment always returns the oldest message ID between the user (58) and the the other user. 
Changing the order by to use sent_time DESC has not changed this.

I am probably missing something obvious - but how can I get the message ID of the most recent message rather than the oldest by changing this query?

Comment: I don't know mysql, but this code is only standard sql, and it is clear that there is no operator in here that reduces the rows returned to 1. Thus, in contrast to what you say, this query should return ALL messageIDs between 58 and the other(corr). It is probably one of the subsequent application levels that limits the result to one row.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis the group by seems to limit the output to 1 row per each combination of users? When I run this directly in the mysql server I get one row for each combination of sender/recipient user IDs and the message ID is always the earliest in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't give the results you want because as soon as you use `GROUP BY` it selects random values for all unaggregated columns. I think you can simplify your query to avoid this problem:

```
SELECT id, 
    CASE WHEN to_user = '58' THEN from_user ELSE to_user END AS corr
FROM messages m
WHERE (to_user = 58 OR from_user = 58) AND
    sent_time = (SELECT MAX(sent_time) 
                 FROM messages m1 
                 WHERE m1.to_user = 58 OR m1.from_user = 58)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you can try following sql:

```
select
max(sub.id),
sub.corr
from 
    (
        select
            m.id,
            m.sent_time,
            (case when m.to_user = '58' then m.from_user else m.to_user end) as corr
        from
            messages m
        where
            (
                from_user = '58' OR
                to_user = '58'
            )
        order by
            m.sent_time desc
    ) as sub
group by
    sub.corr
```